# use activeadmin to have ability of creating accounts for a devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i was thinking to create a webapp for my college in which students can upload there assignments and teachers can have a check on them and give marks. i have used devise gem to make students authentication. now i decide to use activeadmin and give the ability of creating teachers account to only admin. how is it possible. or is there any other option for it to be done...

my plan is to give the ability of creating teachers account only to a single admin and grant teachers the ability to access the assignments uploaded by students. help in creating the webapp please!!!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what part of this you need help with and what you've done so far?

Comment: I just want that when admin is logged in, he gets displayed with ability to create accounts, when a teacher is logged in he has the ability to see the activity of students. and also when a student is logged in, he has the ability to post there assignments.
i have made a students model using devise gem, a portal model using scaffolding which shows up when a student logs in.
i want to use the same sign in page for the logging in of teachers, as well as admin. but the new accounts creation ability musit be only with admin.